# SqlException is missing on dotnet core 3?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I had a C# code on dotnet core 2.2 that looks like this:

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
// ...
if (e.InnerException != null && e.InnerException is SqlException && e.InnerException.Message.Contains("Cannot insert duplicate key row"))
```

I upgraded the dotnet core version to version 3.

Now I get this error message (compile time):

```
The type name 'SqlException' could not be found in the namespace 'System.Data.SqlClient'. This type has been forwarded to assembly 'System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' Consider adding a reference to that assembly.
```

I checked it with a class view and its looks like the requested file (`SqlException`) is not there (`System.Data.SqlClient`).

What is the replacement of this file?

Comment: There is another package Microoft.Data.SqlClient. you can use it.

Comment: @Aravind not an optimal solution, but likely would work. I am adding an answer I thing is better and mentioning the reference as an alternative. BTW, I am gonna spit in your coffee, you got a typo!

Answer (score 3):

### Solution

Install `System.Data.SqlClient` from Nuget (in my case v4.7) solved the issue.

Comment: `SqlExcepcion` inherits from `DbException` OP could use it instead and there would need no extra dependencies.

Comment: For my case Ijust need to replace `System.Data.SqlClient` to `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient`

Answer (score 1):

Because you want yo check if the inner exception is database related and [SqlExcepcion inherits from DbException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception?view=netcore-3.0) you could just change the type you are checking against.

```
if (e.InnerException != null && e.InnerException is DBException && e.InnerException.Message.Contains("Cannot insert duplicate key row"))
```

As an alternative you could just add the reference to the SQL Server Nuget (System.Data.SqlClient)